# How to create a 3D scatter plot?

Tags: c#, 3d, plot, scatter-plot

I have been doing some research on 3d scatter plots with C#. So far I have found a [library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFChart3D.aspx) that is somewhat working for me. However, not necessarily as flexible as I need it to be. Since all I require is to create a fixed 3D scatter plot, are there other alternatives to 3d plotting using the `Point3D` structure in C# or any other alternatives that don't require me bringing in a 3rd party library and that might allow for better flexibility?

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to create a 3D scatter plot with [ILNumerics](http://ilnumerics.net/):

```
var colors
  = new[] { Color.Red, Color.Black, Color.Blue, Color.Green /*...*/ };

ILArray<float> data = ILMath.zeros<float>(
  3,
  colors.Length);

ILArray<float> colorData = ILMath.zeros<float>(
  3,
  colors.Length);

int index = 0;
foreach (var p in colors)
{
  data[0, index] = p.GetHue();
  data[1, index] = p.GetSaturation();
  data[2, index] = p.GetBrightness();
  colorData [0, index] = p.R / 255.0f;
  colorData [1, index] = p.G / 255.0f;
  colorData [2, index] = p.B / 255.0f;
  index++;
}

var points = new ILPoints()
{
  Positions = data,
  Colors = colorData 
};

points.Color = null;

var plot = new ILPlotCube(twoDMode: false)
{
  Rotation = Matrix4.Rotation(new Vector3(1, 1, 0.1f), 0.4f),
  Projection = Projection.Orthographic,
  Children = { points }
};

plot.Axes[0].Label.Text = "Hue";
plot.Axes[1].Label.Text = "Saturation";
plot.Axes[2].Label.Text = "Brightness";

this.ilPanel1.Scene = new ILScene { plot };
```

Quite easy to learn and use, however has some serious problems with my graphics card (it's *Intel® Processor Graphics 2000* so I don't blame them...) - only the GDI renderer is working, with not very astonishing performance.

Comment: Hoping the GDI rendering is fixed by now, else, maybe research my [3d scatter charting](http://www.gigasoft.com).  I'm pretty confident my charts will function with the Intel 2000 graphics chipset, via DirectX. It's only an 18 meg no hassle download and in seconds you could tinker with the bits, interesting none the less.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need the plot to appear in your your C# application, I can suggest [HypnoLog](https://github.com/SimonLdj/hypnolog-server), an Open source tool I been working on which will display the plot in a web browser acting as an output log.

The advantages over the `ILNumerics` library which was suggested in the other answer are:

- It's open source and free to use
- You are completely flexible selecting any plotting library for the browser
- You can keep using your own data structure in the code (like `Point3D`)

There is no built-in visualizer for 3d scatter plot right now in HypnoLog, but you can easily [create your own visualizer](https://github.com/SimonLdj/hypnolog-server/blob/master/doc/AddingVisualizersAndWindows.md#how-to-add-a-visualizer). I can suggest using [plotly 3D Scatter Plots](https://plot.ly/javascript/3d-scatter-plots/).
HypnoLog will help you sending the data from your C# application to the visualizer you created in the browser. See [HypnoLog-CSharp](https://github.com/SimonLdj/hypnolog-csharp) library for easy use of HypnoLog in C#.