# Drawing 3D points in a graph

Tags: c#, mvvm, 3d

i need to draw a 3D graph of points (x,yz). Each point is connected to one other.
Whats the best way of doing these task in MVVM with C#.
I thought about a collection with the single points.

Best regards!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - MSChart is [not really recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244699/how-to-plot-a-3d-graph-to-represent-an-object-in-space/40245156#40245156) ;-)

Comment: I am using WPF.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in 3D graphing library in .net. So your options are:

1. Use a third party library, see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/
2. Write your own 3D graph. Wpf support 3D graphics, so this is certainly possible. But it will require a fair bit of effort and understanding of the concepts. To much to explain in a simple post. See [3D graphics overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/graphics-multimedia/3-d-graphics-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to get you started.