# How to render a spline in C# using VTK?

Tags: c#, .net, spline

I want to render some splines in my winform application. Does VTK support this? If not, is there any other library in C# can?

Comment: Their Wiki claims to have a Spline-Widget: https://vtk.org/Wiki/File:SplineWidget.png Have you done any research whatsoever?

Comment: All GDI+ curves/paths are splines.

Comment: @TaW sorry i didn't make my question clear, what i want to render in my application is a space curve. I think GDI+ can only draw 2D curves. Am i right?

Comment: @Fildor I found a example on their website, I'm not sure if it fits my requirement, i'll try it later.

Comment: _GDI+ can only draw 2D curves. Am i right?_ - Yes, afasik. And I would not advise to use [MSChart in 3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244699/how-to-plot-a-3d-graph-to-represent-an-object-in-space/40245156#40245156), as it has way too many issues..